# .bat gerador de números

Tags: windows, script, cmd, comandos

necessito de um .bat que gere números aleatórios com os caracteres 123 em sequências diferentes tipo 123,321,213,312,231 de preferência utilizando um numero de cada sem ser assim 212. mas se só der de outro jeito também pode ser! Alguém pode me ajudar? Estou precisando o mais rápido possível!

Comment: procure como gerar permutações de sequências. Escreva um código com o que você tentou e peça ajuda novamente. Em '.bat' não acho que vai ser simples.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro você conhecer o [Autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/).

Ele é um script programável que você deixa ativo na barra de tarefas do windows.

Com ele você pode fazer praticamente tudo, sem grandes dificuldades.

Acho que vale a pena investir um tempinho para conhecer.

Comment: Obrigado! vou dar uma olhada!